# Is the function u=0?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a domain .

If $ \int_{\Omega}\nabla u(x)\nabla \phi(x)=0$ for all test functions $\phi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ , does u=0 hold ?

Comment: where does $u$ live? as written, of course not, since $u=10$ works

Comment: $ u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ solves $- \Delta u=0 in \Omega , u=0 \ on \ the \ boundary $

Comment: If $u \in H^1_{\color{red}0}$ then $u=0$. Just take $\phi=u$ to obtain $\nabla u =0$ and use the boundary condition $u_{|\partial \Omega}=0$ to conclude $u=0$.